# How do I use a return statement within a static method for an object class?

Tags: java, oop, static, return, boolean

I am currently working on a Triangle related object class, and I am having trouble with my static method.

For the homework assignment, my professor specifically wants this

A static method `isTriangle()` that accepts 3 double values as lengths of sides and returns `true` if the given sides can form a triangle, otherwise returns `false`. [help: sides s1, s2 and s3 can form a triangle IF s1 < s2 + s3 and s2 < s1 + s3 and s3 < s1 + s2].

What I currently have is:

```
package Homework;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
  Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  private double side1;
  private double side2;
  private double side3;

  public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3) {
    this.side1 = s1;
    this.side2 = s2;
    this.side3 = s3;
  }    

  public static boolean isTriangle(Triangle verify) {
    return (side1 < side2 + side3 && side2 < side1 + side3 && side3 < side1 + side2);
  }    
}
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field.
```

Comment: Actually I believe that you're looking for a shortcut asking this on StackOverflow. Just follow the assignment: your `isTriangle` has nothing to do with the proposed in the whole exercice.

Comment: If you want to access the fields of your `Triangle` object `verify`, then you should use `verify.side1` etc.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm not really asking for a shortcut or a blatant answer. This has more to do with why I'm getting an error message.

Comment: @Zepheriah Check my answer. I'm not going to provide you the solution since it's very obvious: read the exercice carefully!

Comment: @Roshana Don't give answer for the sake of points. Let him/her understand the concept first.

Comment: You should really ask yourself why this needs to be a static method and not an instance method. Making it an instance method makes more sense here (and then you don't need to pass the object as a parameter).

Answer (score 3):

You can't access instance variable inside a static method. You can only access static variables or static methods directly inside a static method .So use the parameter in isTriangle() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the static function to the following:

```
public static boolean isTriangle(Triangle verify) {
  return verify.getSide1() < (verify.getSide2() + verify.getSide3()) 
     && verify.getSide2() < (verify.getSide1() + verify.getSide3()) 
     && verify.getSide3() < (verify.getSide1() + verify.getSide2());
}
```

FYI: I have not tested the actual code.
You should also use getter/setter or make the private fields to public to use `verify.side1` instead of `verify.getSide1()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parameter `verify` in your static method, instead of fields in Triangle class. Eg:

```
public static boolean isTriangle(Triangle verify) {
    return (verify.side1 < verify.side2 + verify.side3 && verify.side2 < verify.side1 + verify.side3 && verify.side3 < verify.side1 + verify.side2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access instance variables inside a `static` method. Hence the error "cannot make static reference to the non-static fields". I do not want to give away more clues as this is an assignment and you should figure it out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access instance members from a static one - this isn't ever possible -. This is the source of the error.

About the assignment, just follow its instructions:

> A static method isTriangle() that accepts 3 double values as lengths of sides and returns true **if the given sides can form a triangle** <--

I don't see a static method with 3 inputs of type `double`. You'll get the answer yourself if you just do what your teacher has proposed you in the whole exercice.